# How would i make a button in Java onto a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am coding on Android and using terminal IDE to compile my code. However, for some reason when I compile, it says the `Button` code is wrong.

```
package BlahBlahBlah;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class blahblahblah extends JFrame{
    JFrame w = new JFrame();
    w.setVisible(true);
    w.setSize(1366, 768);

    Button sb = new JButton();
    sb.addListener(this);
    add(sb);
}
```

It keeps saying illegal start of type or identifier expected which as you see there's a identifier in the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button sb = new JButton();
```

A "Button" without the "J" is not the same as a "JButton".

In Swing components start with a "J".

Comment: So just a syntax error is the problem by the way thanks for the fast response

Comment: there is also a bunch more errors in the code like in                                               
    w.setSize(1366, 768)                                                                                                            
                     ^ identifier expected is what my compiler says

Comment: @PheonixVX, Start with Swing basics. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). Download the working code example and modify it. The examples will show you how to better structure your code.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try.

Comment: Also in the Listener for the button i don't know if i did it right for the Button because i used to have Button.addListener but know i have sb.addListener so just asking would the code compile without an error

Comment: @PheonixVX, This is basic programming learning how to read compiler error messages. We don't have time to teach you programming. It is expected that you understand basic Java before getting into more complicated programing like Swing. I gave you a link to the tutorial. The tutorial has dozens of working examples of basic Swing programs and features (yes there is also one on how to use buttons). So read the tutorial and download the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code inside a method.

```
public class blahblahblah extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.setSize(1366, 768);

        Button sb = new JButton();
        sb.addListener(this);
        add(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: My compiler shows that as a error before whenever i had it in a method so i just removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove `sb.addListener(this);` or implement our class with `ActionListener` and add it's umimplemented methods to your class. Also, do some changes like:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class blahblahblah extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    public blahblahblah() 
    {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.setSize(1366, 768);

        JButton sb = new JButton();
        sb.addActionListener(this);
        add(sb);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        blahblahblah b = new blahblahblah();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // TODO Your Stuff

    }
}
```